# How do I reset a MySQL column in a table every year?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a column named `lv_casual` in a table called `tbl_employees`. I need to reset the column to `0` at a specific date every year.

Comment: Try using SQL sequence, something like in this post - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/216586

Comment: @shri_world The stack exchange example uses SQL Server, here its MySQL

Comment: @Aswin Haridas, You can add a cron job to do that anyway.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL event schedule. Providing an example below.

You have to enable the schedular first

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Then create the event

```
    CREATE EVENT your_event_name
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR
    STARTS '2021-10-12 00:00:00'
    DO
    UPDATE table SET column=0;
```

Check [MySQL document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) for creating event

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use a cron job to run once per year at end of the year, create a script that will reset all the records on that column to 0.
    
    /usr/local/bin/ea-php99 /home2/accounname/https://example.com/cron_execute_file

okay bro this how your execute file should look like cron_execute_file.php

     <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";
    
    // Create connection to db

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $sql = "UPDATE employees SET leaves='12' WHERE leaves >= 0";
    
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
    
    $conn->close();
    ?> 


    N/B:  [@Shaido][1] and any dauche bag thinking of, Please stop editing my answers, just give your own answers,  adding fullstops and grammar to my answers to gain budges is a lame thing  note this is not a English grammar class. Stay away from my answers, give your own answers. Polite Notice failure to I'll send some visitors to you machines. 


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7579547/shaido
```